# Images of template not rendering when send through Handlebar using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, handlebars.js, nodemailer

```js
// SendMail.js(NodeMailer File)

var source = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'test.hbs'), 'utf8');
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

let image2 = base64Img.base64Sync('./images/logo.png')
var replacements = { username: "John Doe", img2: image2 };
var htmlToSend = template(replacements);

let mailOption = {
    from: config.get("nodemailer_email"),
    to: email,
    subject: emailSubject,
    html: htmlToSend,      
};
```

```js
// template.hbs

<html>
    <head><title>Reset Your Password</title></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Click this!</h1>
        <p>
            <h1>{{username}}</h1>
            <div><img src="{{img2}}" /></div>
            <div><img src={{img2}} /></div>
            <div style="background-image: url({{{img2}}});"></div>
            <div style="background-image: url('hands.png');"></div>
            <div style="background-image: url('./hands.png');"></div>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

** Tried different methods to render image, none of them worked. please help us find the solution for this problem...............................................................................................................................
**

Comment: Try to explain the meaning of "none of them worked". What is happening currently?

Comment: We used various ways to deal with this problem.